# Rails Model class relations in ternary many-many case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relational-database

I have a 'users' table, 'groups' table and 'invitations' table(join table). I am trying to build a relation between 'invitors'(class_name 'User'), 'invitees'(class_name 'User') and 'groups'(class_name 'Group') where 'invitations'(class_name 'Invitation') is the join table with foreign keys 'invitor_id', 'invitee_id' and 'group_id'.

(Many 'Invitors' can give 'Invitations' to Many 'Invitees' to join Many 'Groups')

I tried several ways by explicitly specifying :foreign_key and :class_name in my Model classes, but in vain. I have just started learning the 'activerecord relations' concepts in rails, and i really want to make efficient use of it. Can someone help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve here, in `ActiveRecord` terms, is a "self referential" association.  Ryan Bates provides a great example that answers your situation almost exactly:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

In his example you can replace "`Friendship`"  with your idea of an "`Invitation`".  You will need to add a `group_id` to his Friendship model to keep track of which `Group` the `Invitation` is related to.